# Strong material but transparent for high energy electron beam

Tags: electrons, material-science, radiation, vacuum

I'm looking for a material which is strong enough to cover a 2mm hole between two chambers with one containing a ultra high vacuum and the other atmospheric pressure and at the same time it should be as transparent as possible for a high energetic electron beam (15keV-30keV). I read about mica sheets which are used for Geiger–Müller tube windows.
Will the beam still be focused and nearly as strong after passing the window and is the material strong enough? Or is there another better material?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a hard ask. How intense is the electron beam? And how much loss and/or energy spread do you consider acceptable? How big an aperture do you need to cover?

Comment: To get MeV ion beams out of vacuum, people have used thin Mylar or thin silicon nitride membranes. But, those beams are typically in the ~10nA range. Differential pumping is another alternative. In any event, a fast-acting valve to protect the vacuum system is a must. You will get some scattering through the thin membranes. Strength is less of an issue than you might think, and beam heating is perhaps more of an issue than you might think.

Comment: We are talking about a beam with ~200 mA. Differential pumping is my current set up but I thought there might be a better alternative. I would accept a "big" energy loss if the beam would still be focused and let's say has 50% of it's intensity. But high energy loss would mean high heat and probably destruction of the membrane, right? Some scattering would not be a problem, I would just use a second aperture.